# How to open 3d .raw image (file) whit opencv?

Tags: opencv

I have some big (1,82GB) .raw files. Here are the information that I have:

dimension: 3
sizes: 2550 2550 301
type: uint8
encoding: raw

I don´t know how can I open it .I´m new in opencv. I try to read it

```
int main(void)
char * imgpath = "xxx.raw"
char str[125];
sprintf(str, "C:\\Program Files\\OpenCV-2.3.1\\samples\\c\\%s", imgpath);
FILE * f = fopen(str,"rb")
if ( !f )
{
    printf("bad path : %s\n", str);
    return -1;
}
```

How to create image now? With Mat?

Comment: where is that from ? what's the 3rd dimension ?

Comment: Have you tried reading the introduction to openCV? http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html